# how to conditionally show a content editor webpart

Tags: content-editor-web-part

how to conditionally show a content editor webpart based on user currently logged in.
I have 2 links on my webpart page, and i need to show one of the link to only a specific user.

is there a out of the box webpart available that can do this. I'm also working on target audience part, but for a different requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you mentioned, audience targetting would be the route I would take.

Instead of using a content editor web part though, I'd probably use a link list with the items being either audience targetted, or have item level permissions applied.  The choice is yours depending on if you just need targetting or actual security.

Answer (score 4):

As Eric mentions, your requirements may drive you in different directions, but you could also use some script in the CEWP to determine whether it should show itself or parts of itself. The security vs. obscurity question will determine whether script is an acceptable approach.